# How to setOnItemSelectedListener on several Dynamically created spinners

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-spinner

I have an Activity where I need to create 1 or more spinners dynamically according to an external DB.

SOme of this spinner items have to show a dialog according what value does the spinner has. For example the spinner has this options:
-Own
-Rental
-Family House
If the user selects Rental I have to show a dialog (or anything) asking him how much does he pays per month. If he selects own, or family nothing should happen.

After I create the layout with the spinners, edittexts, etc. Im using something like this:

```
for(int q=0;q<=parent.getChildCount();q++){

        View v = parent.getChildAt(q);
        if (v instanceof Spinner) {
            Spinner res = (Spinner) v;
            res.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    //Here its supposed to show dialog if the option is "RENT"
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I do this the "setOnItemSelectedListener" only sets for the last spinner on the layout.

How can I do what Im trying? I dont know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would probably be to make one Listener as a variable and use that for all of your spinners. To do this, you would not set it as you are currently (using the anonymous inner-class style) and instead would do this:

```
//This goes outside of the method
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = 
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("Spinner Selected ID = " + parent.getId());
        /*
        Put a check here for which one is being selected.
        While you could use the parent to check, in your case, it will be easier
        to use something from your DB table as a unique identifier (maybe a column
        name would be ideal? Your pick)
         */
        //Show your dialogs here
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        return;
    }
};

//This is the method you have where you are iterating the parent object
private void doStuff(){
    for(int q=0;q<=parent.getChildCount();q++){
        View v = parent.getChildAt(q);
        if (v instanceof Spinner) {
            Spinner res = (Spinner) v;
            res.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck to ya!

Comment: Same thing happening. It only applies to the last spinner.

Comment: I just wrote some test code and it seems like it is working on my end. Couple of questions, is the issue that the click listener is not registering? Or is it that the data is not being set correctly into the spinners? Or something else?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. The problem is that click listener only applies to the last spinner. I mean I have 5-6 spinners. Listener only applies on the 6th spinner. Listener only works for that spinner. if I want to listener print an item for example, only prints the last spinner items.

Comment: It sounds to me like it is an adapter problem. My recommendation to pinpoint the issue is, add a print statement to the listener like I did in the updated answer. If you select 3 different spinners and get back 3 different IDs, then you know the issue is with your adapters. If you get the same ID 3 times, then you know it is with the listener.